# .NET Core MVC Can Ajax Redirect Page with Model

Tags: .net, ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I am posting my data from front end using ajax to the backend controller, what I am expecting is that the controller generate a model and redirect a new View with the model; but it never gets redirected. Is it possible to redirect inside the controller? Not Ajax?

I have looked some other threads saying the redirect code need to be written in the Ajax Success function, which it works but I am not able to pass the model to the new view. Is there any way to pass a model alone with ajax redirect? (I cannot pass my data through URL because the amount of data is kind of huge). Please advice, Thank you in advance.

**Controller Method:**

```
public IActionResult Input([FromBody] IEnumerable<HistTable> Input)
{
    //Some Code
    return View("/views/test/test.cshtml", model);
}
```

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/test/input",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (e) {
                    //How to pass the model?
                    //window.location.replace(link);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why not have your view that you redirect to grab the data again?

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem? If it is solved, please accept it as the answer, otherwise, please tell me your still existing problems.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to redirect inside the controller? Not Ajax?

In fact, if ajax is completely aside, the real redirect operation cannot be realized only inside the controller.

You should achieve it combine ajax and controller by these two ways: **TempData** or **Session** to achieve this function.

And note that since you are passing multiple pieces of data, please **`serialize` them into json before storing, and get them through `deserialization`**.

### 1.Session

In this way, **pass the data through the session in the controller**, and then **redirect to the test view in success function in ajax**.

First [enable `Session`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in the startup.cs file of the core project.

Then, use the following code:

```
   public IActionResult Test(List<Employee> model)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("model") != null)
            {
                model = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Employee>>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("model"));
            } 
            return View(model);
        }
        public IActionResult Input([FromBody] List<Employee> Input)
        { 

            //Some Code
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("model", System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Input)); 
            return Content("/test/test");
        }
```

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Test/input",
                //dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(
                    [{ Id: 1, FirstName: 'a', LastName: 'v', Gender: 'male' },
                    { Id: 2, FirstName: 'b', LastName: 'v', Gender: 'female' },
                    { Id: 3, FirstName: 'c', LastName: 'v', Gender: 'male' }]),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (e) {
                    window.location.replace(e);
                }
            });
```

### 2.TempData

First, you need to pass model by `TempData["data"]` from Input to Test action by  `RedirectToAction("test")` , because you are passing multiple data.

```
public IActionResult Test(List<Employee> model)
        {  
            if (TempData["data"] != null)
            {
                model = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Employee>>(TempData["data"].ToString()); 
                TempData.Keep();
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        public IActionResult Input([FromBody] List<Employee> Input)
        {
            //Some Code 
            TempData["data"] = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Input); 
            return RedirectToAction("test"); 
        }
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Test/input",
                //dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(
                    [{ Id: 1, FirstName: 'a', LastName: 'v', Gender: 'male' },
                    { Id: 2, FirstName: 'b', LastName: 'v', Gender: 'female' },
                    { Id: 3, FirstName: 'c', LastName: 'v', Gender: 'male' }]),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (e) {
                    window.location.replace("/test/test");
                }
            });
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'd normally send it as a POST via the body. Or another option is to send some sort of identifier over in the url and use that to do a get of the model on the other side.